# Bootstrap header alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In laptop or desktop screen it works fine, but in smaller screen the header link not aligned correctly, so for example, in mobile view there is a big gap between headers and in Ipad screen the headers pushed down ! I try max and min width but that did not solve my problem .

code:

```
 <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container" id="testing">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button id="icon" type="button" data-target="#test" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" aria-expanded="true">
                    <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
               <img src="/pic/photoHeader.jpg" height="60" width="190" />
            </div>

            <div id ="test" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true" >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About Company</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Business Units 

                            </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Engineering">Solution Engineering Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Bioforce">Solution Bioforce Sdn Bhd </a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/Biogen">Solution Biogen Sdn Bhd</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/BusinessUnits/AC">Solution A&C Technology Sdn Bhd</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li  class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Investor Relations</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Directors">Directors</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/CorporateStructure">Corporate Structure </a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/News">News</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Events">Events</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/InvestorRelation/Anno">Announcements</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li  class="dropdown">
                        <a runat="server" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contact Us</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact/Whist">Whistleblowing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="login1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx">Admin Login</asp:LinkButton>

                        </li>
                        <li><asp:LinkButton ID="Logout" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" onclick="Logout_Click">(logout)</asp:LinkButton></li>


                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Problems shown here:

[image]

Comment: what is pushed down?

Comment: see right image, the headers pushed down